# extract content from a txt file and making txt files with that content using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have never tried this, and I have been searching to see the best way to make a script that can extract content from a txt file into their own txt files

Now I managed this and it extracts all content into their own txt files, but not sure how to make it use the extracted content as the txt filename

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "a.txt"') do (
    cd > %%a.txt
)
endlocal
```

so I have this

Content of my a.txt:

```
  All_type_2020
  All_Foods_2021
```

and this is what I get

```
All_type_2020All_Foods_2021.txt
```

I have tested many different scripts, and the closes I have gotten was with the script above

my goal is to have this results

```
All_type_2020.txt

All_Foods_2021.txt
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want, you want text files named like `All_type_2020.txt` and `All_Foods_2021.txt`, ok with what content ? What does `| -- All_type_2020` mean to you ? is that the exact contents of `a.txt` ?

Comment: @thecarpy - yes, I did this to show what is inside `| -- ` the `a.txt` - I was not sure how to disclose what is inside the txt file, so yes, inside my txt file I have 100 different messages, like what you see above, and I want to extract every line into txt file, but with their own file name

Comment: I updated my question a little better

Comment: The script you have submitted as and answer is not correct, and neither is the answer posted by thecarpy. `delims` is not required, and in this case not preferred over `tokens`. Is this what you were trying to do.```@For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=*^ EOL^= %%G In ("a.txt") Do @(Echo %%~G) 1>"%%~G.txt"```

Comment: @Compo - Thank you -half of what I was looking for - I didn't need it to copy the file name as content - only to the filename - I might be able to use this on other tasks - The script that I fixed does exactly what I was looking for - the goal was to place the content of the `a.txt` file as file name

Comment: Okay, even simpler then, ```@For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=*^ EOL^= %%G In ("a.txt") Do @CD.>"%%~G.txt"```. Note the missing space between **`.`** and **`>`**; this way it should create empty, (0 byte), files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `thecarpy` and `Pedro` I was able to figure out my mistake

Here is the correct script

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=*" %%a in ('type "a.txt"') do (
    cd. > %%a.txt
)
endlocal
```

This is the contents of `a.txt`

```
CONTENTS
All_type_2020
All_Foods_2021
All_type_2021
All_Foods_2022
All_type_2022

The Results
All_type_2020.txt
All_Foods_2021.txt
All_type_2021.txt
All_Foods_2022.txt
All_type_2022.txt
```

Both of these will do the job 
@For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=*^ EOL^= %%G In ("a.txt") Do @CD.>"%%~G.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what it is you're seeking, however I might have something that nevertheless might help you.

The code I wrote below will check for each sentence in "a.txt" if the first word is equal to "blue" if so it will output it into a txt file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (a.txt) do if "%%a" == "blue" (
echo - %%a is blue >blue.txt
) else (
if "%%a" == "red" echo - %%a is red >red.txt)

pause
```

This is an oversimplified version of what I think you're trying to do, but hopefully it can help. To change how the document filters look around the website and you will surely find ways for it to help.

Comment: Thank you, not what I am looking for BUT it did help - `delims` was the code I was missing - I did test it, but I forgot to use this `*`

Answer (score 0):

So, contents of `a.txt`

```
All_type_2020
All_Foods_2021
All_type_2021
All_Foods_2022
All_type_2022
```

Contents of my CMD file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=*" %%a in (a.txt) do (
echo. >%%a.txt
)
```

In the directory, I then have these empty files:

```
11/10/2022  10:22 AM    <DIR>          .
11/10/2022  10:22 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/10/2022  10:22 AM                77 a.txt
11/10/2022  10:22 AM                 3 All_Foods_2021.txt
11/10/2022  10:22 AM                 3 All_Foods_2022.txt
11/10/2022  10:22 AM                 3 All_type_2020.txt
11/10/2022  10:22 AM                 3 All_type_2021.txt
11/10/2022  10:22 AM                 3 All_type_2022.txt
           6 File(s)             92 bytes
```

Comment: Thank you - very good, I found the issue - I was using the wrong code `delims` was the right code - I did test it but I forgot to use this `*`

Comment: the empty files could be because of this `.` after `echo`

Comment: I never understood what you wanted in the files, hence why I specifically mentioned empty files.

Comment: what you had was on point, almost 100% exactly what I wanted -I have single words per line in a `txt` file just like in your example and to extract every line to their own `filename.txt` but the 3 is not correct - so if you want to see exactly what I am doing copy my script and make an `a.txt` and copy your example from here `So, contents of a.txt` and paste it into the txt file and run the script, it will do exactly as your results but minus the 3 and minus the empty space

Comment: I have updated my answer, using your example